# Storing file from external device

Tags: android

I am building a application which reads the data from any external device and directly stores in mobile in text format. It is something like [ origin software] which allows to connect external source to computer and stores in computer in some file format. Can i achieve this by directly plugging external device and store in mobile. If so should i have to write seperate code to store values in mobile.

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. The _android_ tag suggests that you are writing an Android app, but Android devices are usually USB slaves rather than USB hosts. What you want to plug in, and where to? USB is asymmetric. There's no slave-slave or host-host interaction. If some device has only USB slave sockets, it cannot be an USB host. Some Android devices can be USB hosts, but most of them cannot.

Comment: yes i am trying to build a application in android. As i have specified    i should collect some data from external device [ This application is creating for the physics students who takes reading from any device for plotting graph]. My question is if i connect USB to that external device and to android mobiles will i able to store those read values into some file and store in mobile memory directly? will it automatically craets file in mobile or i need to write seperate code to create file and store values into it.

Comment: As i told in the question it is like a "origin" software. Physics students connects their external device to computer through USB then it will generate a file with the readings. Then they will import that file and plot the graph. I need to do same application in android.